# How to block attacks from "BOT/0.1 (BOT for JCE)" using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, bots, joomla-content-editor

I have noticed an increase in attacks from this user agent:

```
BOT/0.1 (BOT for JCE)
```

Request line is:

```
POST /index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin&plugin=imgmanager&file=imgmanager&version=1576&cid=20 HTTP/1.1
```

I have tried to block the bot with the following code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent “BOT for JCE” bad_bot
<Limit GET POST>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```

But the above is not stopping the bots/attacks. How can I stop them?

Comment: For the record, this type of question is welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BOT/0\.[0-9]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Comment: @user3219811 did it??